# How to convert Text to numbers in Excel 2010?

Tags: excel, excel-2010

[image]I want to convert the numbers from text format to numbers so tha i can make the average or sum of the whole columns.

I tried all the possible ways asfar as i read in many blogs, but nothing works.

> There is  no **Green** mark on the cell nor a quote **'**
>
> Tried copying an empty cell and select required cells and paste special methods also.

Comment: if you use =Numbervalue() are you able to do what you want?

Comment: Not actually @Jorvik77

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are using a French version of Excel. In this case a number should be 6,04 and not 6.04

Do a find and replace of . for , and you should be able to change the format to a number if it is not done automatically.

Comment: Thanks for reminding, i really forgot this ';' to ','

Answer (score 0):

You can either:

1. change the values to numbers
2. use a formula that can handle text-type numeric values

Say we have data in column **A** that is *Text*.  This formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(A:A))
```

can give you the **sum** without having to convert first:

[image]